# Grouping Data with dynatable

Tags: php, jquery, dynatable

I would like to check if there is any way that i could group data with the jquery plugin dynatable. I would like data to be displayed as below.

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Accounts</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Designation</td><td>Email</td>
   </tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Designation</td><td>Email</td>
   </tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Designation</td><td>Email</td>
   <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Customer Services</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Designation</td><td>Email</td>
   </tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Designation</td><td>Email</td>
   </tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Designation</td><td>Email</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

I was able to generate the table in the intended format with php however i would like to use dynatable to make the content more dynamic.

If anyone could assist me in getting this done it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is pretty much what's described in these two issues on the dynatable repo:

- [#19 - Detail "row" that is not actually its own row (in the DOM)](https://github.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable/issues/19)
- [#30 - colspan support in head](https://github.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable/issues/30)

It's not yet supported, but I'll be working to add support for it.